# Proxy PAC Script didn't work for several URL

Tags: javascript, url, proxy, pac

Ladies and Gentlemen.

Recently, my ISP block several URL.

I tried Freegate and it's work fined without problem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freegate

but, it's too lazied to switch proxy manually hand by hand, so I decided to use PAC Script to automatic switch URL.

Here is my script.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)

{

    // variable strings to return

    var proxy_yes = "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8580";

    var proxy_no = "DIRECT";

    if (shExpMatch(url, "http://www.nyaa.se*")) { return proxy_yes; }

    if (shExpMatch(url, "http://sukebei.nyaa.se*")) { return proxy_yes; }

    if (shExpMatch(url, "http://checkip.dyndns.com*")) { return proxy_yes; }

    if (shExpMatch(url, "http://www.whatismyip.com*")) { return proxy_yes; }

    // Proxy anything else

    return proxy_no;

}
```

When I access checkip.dyndns.com and whatismyip.com, Its success and show freegate proxy IP without problem.
(freegate use local proxy 127.0.0.1:8580)

But when I access nyaa.se and sukebei.nyaa.se, the browser cannot access correctly, and show offline browsing instead.

I think my script did not getting wrong. but maybe it'll be related about nyaa URL mechanical itself.

Everybody please help me, what is my script wrong. Or need to config with more complex script instead.

Thanks for wasting your time to see my problem.

Comment: You are missing the point of the proxy, the proxy url should point to a proxy server and not a website.
The code/conf that switch urls should be in the proxy server, not in your proxy.pac.